# Fragment title alone changes Screen remains same after navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am navigating from one fragment to another fragment but my title alone changes my screen remains same. In the background the new fragment is up and running. This happens only when i navigate during any api call in the background.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (main_fragment_container != null) {
        ft.replace(main_fragment_container.getId(), fragment, fragment.getClass().getName());
    }
    if (isStackNeeded) {
        ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    }

    ft.commit();
```

Comment: But as per my knowledge, there is no relation between UI and background thread. May be its dependant on any result from the api?

Comment: But If i stop tat background Thread tat navigation happens properly